# Display text over image with a filter using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place some text over an image that has a background color as a tint and opacity.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and it's possible some classes are overriding each other, but not 100% sure.

This is what I currently have:

`Index.cshtml`:

```
<div class="layer">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-container resume-jumbotron text-white">
        <div class="container-fluid jumbotron-content">
            <h1 class="text-center jumbotron-header mb-4">Hey there, I'm @Model.FullName!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`site.css`:

```css
.jumbotron-container {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: opacity(60%);
}

.resume-jumbotron {
    background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/asp-dot-net/boots.png);
}

.layer {
    background-color: #512F1E;
    position: relative;
}

.jumbotron-header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The above renders this:

[image]

I've tried adding a z-index and position to the `layer` and the header but it screws up the rest of the positioning in the jumbotron.

The currently rendered text shows up behind the background color. How can I position the text so it renders above the `.layer` div despite it being a child of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text isn't showing up behind anything. It has reduced opacity, as set on the jumbotron element. You cannot reset opacity for interior elements. Instead, apply a mask over your background image:

```
.jumbotron-container {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.jumbotron-container::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/du0jax9v/)

I did have to set position on `.jumbotron-content` to keep the pseudo-element behind it.

Replace my black mask color with the rgba equivalent of your hex color. You can eliminate the layer element.